# Why does Django Money show 3 decimals with decimal_places=2?

Tags: python, django, money-format

I'm very confused by this:

```py
>>> from djmoney.models.fields import Money
>>> Money("0.129", "EUR", decimal_places=2)
Money('0.129', 'EUR')
```

I've expected to see `Money('0.12', 'EUR')` or `Money('0.13', 'EUR')`.

I know I can use `round(2)` to get the expected result, but what influence does `decimal_places` have? If it stores the data anyway, why/when should I use the parameter?

[The docs](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=decimal_places#model-usage) are not helpful.

Comment: I don't know anything about that library, but what you print out there is simply what `str()` produces. To me, this seems to be an internal representation.

Comment: Set `CURRENCY_DECIMAL_PLACES` setting to `2` in your django settings. It should work as desired